# Changing default laravel font issue

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, fonts

I'm developing a laravel and bootstrap 4 based system

I tried to change default laravel font Nunito to Lato,

So I changed, app.css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);@charset "UTF-8";
```

to

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);@charset "UTF-8";
```

And replaced all the "Nunito" in my app.css to "Lato",

But still the "Nunito" font loading...

How can I change the font and where am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the style you declare in css file?

Comment: can you change `font-family` of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the font family in the _variable.sass
for your case font-family: 'Finlandica', sans-serif;